# Joining MP3's via commandline with background track

Tags: command-line, sound, ffmpeg, mp3

I'm already taking advatage of two command line utilities. I'm using ffmpeg to convert m4a to mp3, and then I'm combining a few mp3's into one large one using mp3wrap. The resulting file is something like this:

```
BackgroundMusic.mp3 > Audio1.mp3 > Audio2.mp3
```

I need something more like

```
Audio1.mp3 > Audio2.mp3
|_____________________|
           |
  BackgroundMusic.mp3
```

To where the background music runs continuously in the background. Would be nice to be able to change the volume of each track too.

Does anyone know a command line program like mp3wrap but can also add in a background track?

I will not be able to use a GUI program such as Audacity, as all of this will be automated on the server.

Thanks!

Comment: No need for the extra step to convert the m4a to mp3 if you're using `ffmpeg`. Please show the complete console output of `ffmpeg -i Audio1 -i Audio2`.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this with **sox**, a cli audio manipulation tool. For example to concat two files, and mix in a third, then play it:

```
sudo apt-get install sox libsox-fmt-all
sox Audio1.mp3 Audio2.mp3 out1.mp3
sox -m out1.mp3 BackgroundMusic.mp3 out2.mp3
play out2.mp3
```

Comment: if BackgroundMusic.mp3 is longer than Primary.mp3, how can I cut backgroundmusic fit to primary length?

and if Primary.mp3 is longer than BackgroundMusic.mp3, how can I loop backgroundmusic follow primary length?

Comment: You should post this as a new question. There might be answers not using `sox` but some other utility.